# Найти все совершенные числа, меньшие N

Tags: c

Помогите. Столкнулся с очень странной проблемой своего рода. На лабораторную дали задачу. Теоретически все правильно написал, но, к сожалению, ответ выводится не всегда. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка. Заранее спасибо!

*Найти все совершенные числа, меньшие N. Число называется совершенным, если оно равно сумме всех своих делителей за исключением самого числа. Например, 6=1+2+3*

Вот сам код, который, к сожалению, не работает:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<locale.h>
void main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUSSIAN");
int N,i=1,sum=0,n=1;
printf("введите N\n");
scanf("%d",&N);
for (i=1;i<N;i++)
{
for (n=1;n<i;n++)
{
if (i%n==0)
sum=sum+n;
}
if (i==sum) printf("совершенное %d\n", i);
}
}
```

Программа на Си.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы забываете обнулять сумму делителей, в результате чего она постепенно накапливается. 
Исправьте ваши циклы примерно так:

```
for (i = 1; i<N; i++)
{
    sum = 0;  // обнуление суммы делителей
    for (n = 1; n<i; n++)
    {
        if (i%n == 0)
            sum = sum + n;
        }
        if (i == sum) 
        printf("совершенное %d\n", i);

    }
```

Кстати, в плане производительности алгоритм может быть существенно улучшен, например, тем, что  во втором цикле условием остановки можно указать не n < i , а n <= i/2, поскольку очевидно, что все целые делители числа не больше половины этого числа

Comment: @DreamChild, при таком (n < i/2) существенном улучшении число 6 перестанет быть совершенным...

(видимо надо заменить условие с `<` на `<=` ).

Comment: @avp да, разумеется там должно быть не n < i/2, а n <= i/2

Answer (score 1):

Не существует нечётных совершенных чисел меньше `10**1500` (единичка и полторы тысячи нулей) [[Odd perfect numbers are larger than `10**1500` (2012)](http://www.lirmm.fr/~ochem/opn/opn.pdf)]. Для сравнения, самое большое число типа int имеет меньше чем `20` десятичных цифр (64bit int).

Все чётные совершенные числа равны `Mp *(Mp + 1) / 2`, где Mp -- [простое число Мерсенна `(2**p - 1)`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B0_.D0.9C.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.81.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.B0). 
Поэтому [все чётные совершенные числа в двоичной записи содержат сначала p единиц, за которыми следует p—1 нулей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE):

```
110
11100
111110000
1111111000000
1111111111111000000000000
111111111111111110000000000000000
1111111111111111111000000000000000000
1111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000
...
```

где `p` равны [2, 3, 5, 7,  13, 17, 19, 31](https://oeis.org/A000043). На настоящее время (2013), [известно только 48 таких чисел](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#List_of_known_Mersenne_primes). Используя простую таблицу и библиотеку, поддерживающую арифметику с большими числами (чтобы десятичное представление легко напечатать), можно написать [программу, которая выводит все *известные* совершенные числа меньше заданного числа](https://gist.github.com/zed/fb1c6c3ee4511cecaa43).

*Все* чётные совершенные числа известны до числа с 18304103 десятичных цифр
 (`ceil((p+(p-1))*log10(2))`). Cамое большое известное совершенное число `1692963953...6270130176` имеет `34850340` десятичных цифр -- если это число в книжку записать, то по размеру примерно десять "Война и миръ" получится.